# Как пишется "с пылу(,) с жару"?

Tags: фразеология, синтаксис

Нужна ли запятая в выражении "с пылу(,) с жару"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"С пылу с жару" - устойчивое выражение, фразеологизм, поэтому запятая тут не нужна.